# Customise session objects via callbacks in next-auth

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I'm using `"next": "^11.0.1"`, `"next-auth": "^3.27.3"`. I need to customise my session object provided by the hooks to access user information at client-side.  This is my callback code:

```js
callbacks: {    
    async jwt (token, user) {
      console.log(user)
      if (user){
        token = { ...token, username: user?.user, password: user?.password }
        return token
      }
      else {
        return token
      }
    },
    async session( session, token) {
      // Send properties to the client, like an access_token from a provider.
      console.log("session: ", session)
      console.log("passed token:", token)
      return session
    },
},
```

This is my app

```js
const SeatingPage: NextPage = () => {
    const [session, loading] = useSession()

    useEffect(() => {
      if (loading) return
      if (!session) signIn()
    }, [session, loading])

    if (!session) return <p>loading</p>
    return <p>Hello world</p>
}
```

If I understand it right, the token parameter in `jwt()` is what I return in my `authorize()`. The app runs the `jwt()` twice for some reason. However, only in the first call token has the right value being `{user: "xyz", password: "xyz"}` the second time token is an empty object. And `session()` never gets the correct parameter `{ ...token, username: user?.user, password: user?.password }` but always the base token.